# Django | Error al mostrar DetailView con varias imágenes

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

En un template con DetailView se muestra información de Station. Pero una de las columnas (image_station) es ManyToMany para poder mostrar varias imágenes en los detalles de cada estación. (para mostrar en un carousel las imágenes). Devuelve el siguiente error. No se si debería hacer ListView para las imágenes y DetailView para la estación. ¿Todo junto?
Devuelve el siguiente error:

**Error:**

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /station/detail_station/1/
Invalid block tag on line 19: 'station.image_station', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

**Archivo** station.views.py:

```
class StationDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Station
    template_name = "station/detail_station.html"
```

**Archivo** station.models.py

```
class ImageStation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)
    image_imageStation = models.ImageField(upload_to='stations/')

class Station(models.Model):
    name_station = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    image_station = models.ManyToManyField(ImageStation,null=False, blank=False)
```

**Archivo** detail_station.html

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ station.name_station }}</h1>
      {% for img in station.image_station.all %}
        <img style="width:75%;margin:5%" src="{% img.image_imageStation.url %}">
      {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El campo image_station de tu tabla station tienes relación many to many entonces si aqui en el template haces .all te devuelve todos los registros que se encuentran relacionadas a tu station

```
<div>
{% for image in station.image_station.all %}
<img style="width:75%;margin:5%" src="{{ image.image_imageStation.url }}">
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor intenta explicar tu código, las respuestas que son solo código no son bien recibidas.

Comment: Gracias pero devueve: TemplateSyntaxError at /station/detail_station/1/
Invalid block tag on line 18: 'image.image_imageStation.url', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Entiendo el sentido que le quieres dar, pero esto de for no se hace sólo cuando tenemos vista tipo ListView? Yo tengo un DetailView donde quiero mostar las imágenes. Soy nuevo en esto eh...

Comment: si puedes realizar el for ya que image_station te devuelve varios registros de la relación que tiene con tu tabla station actualice la respuesta ya que se me paso que puse {% image.image_imageStation.url %} pero tenia que ser {{ image.image_imageStation.url }} ya que para ejecución de código es {%%} y para mostrar el valor en el html es {{ }}

Comment: Puedes revisar la referencia de esto en https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/ y también los tags que te pueden servir de ayuda en este enlace https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Así es, funciona perfecto: {% for img in station.image_station.all %}
<img style="width:75%;margin:5%" src="{{ img.image_imageStation.url }}">
{% endfor %}